# Spring - how to override internal config file with external file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my spring project I'm having two different conf files which have the same properties.

One of them is in an external directory while the other one is inside the resource of my project.

I want that the external file's properties to override the internal values (if they exist in the external file).

In my configuration class I set the files with the PropertySource annotation:

```
@PropertySources(
{ @PropertySource("file:${HOME}/conf/application.properties"),  
  @PropertySource("classpath:/data.properties")  
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the PropertySource is working like this:
- Read first property file
- Read second (...) property file - if it contains an already given key, it will be overridden.

Check this here: http://javapapers.com/spring/spring-properties-with-propertysource-annotation/

If you want to use it with XML, check also this answer: [What is property resolution order in Spring property placeholder configurer with multiple locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192373/what-is-property-resolution-order-in-spring-property-placeholder-configurer-with)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are working with spring-boot and have fat executable jar,
you can override internal config file properties with external with command line params as follow

```
java -jar your-executable-fat-jar.jar --spring.config.name=external-prop-file-name --spring.config.location=classpath:/application.properties,file://<external-config-file-parent-dir-path-NOT-EXTERNAL-CONFIG-FILE-PATH>
```

where

```
spring.config.name - external config file name
spring.config.location - Locations to look for configuration files
```

**Note:** with above config, spring-boot will look for external-prop-file-name.properties in external directory passed in `spring.config.location`

Answer (score 0):

The order of the declared files is important. If the same key is defined in two or more files, the value associated with the key in the last declared file will override any previous value(s).

From [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html):

> In cases where a given property key exists in more than one .properties file, the last @PropertySource annotation processed will 'win' and override.

So just swap `@PropertySource("file:${HOME}/conf/application.properties")` with `@PropertySource("classpath:/data.properties")`

**Example:**
`@PropertySources({@PropertySource("classpath:/data.properties"),@PropertySource("file:${HOME}/conf/application.properties")})`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot