# How to override internal configuration file in Spring Correctly?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an internal *application.yml* configuration file located in the resources folder on classpath.

I have an external configuration file: */home/username/config.properties* which overrides some fields to run in a server context.

I want the fields in the external config file to override internal file and retain the fields in the internal file if not defined in external file.

The answers suggested [Spring - how to override internal config file with external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759914/spring-how-to-override-internal-config-file-with-external-file) doesn't work.

For example, the following command doesn't works for me:

```
java -jar application.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/,file:///home/minister/config.properties
```

How do I achieve this desired outcome?

**EDIT: This issue only happens on Linux. When I run it with the overriden configuration file on my Windows 10 machine, it works properly.**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have one too many `/`, try:

```
java -jar application.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/,file:/home/minister/config.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the path to file, relative to the .jar file, for example,

```
java -jar application.jar -Dspring.config.location=./config/application.properties
```

or

```
java -jar application.jar -Dspring.config.location=../common/config
```

either of these work. Please refer - [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for further details on how externalized configuration works.

Hope this helps.